# Reading field before batch data insertion

Tags: abap

I'm trying to upload a field through the CS02 transaction using the SM35 transaction that creates a program from a recording, so the code looks like this:

```
perform bdc_dynpro      using 'SAPLCSDI' '0150'.
perform bdc_field       using 'BDC_CURSOR'
                          'RC29P-SORTF(01)'.
perform bdc_field       using 'BDC_OKCODE'
                          '=FCBU'.
```

I think this is the same as selecting the first row of the table.

[image]
The problem I have is that I need to know the value of `RC29P-SORTF(01)` to ensure that the program upload the value of the field correctly. Is there any way to know read `RC29P-SORTF(01)`?.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. Batch-Input is input-only, and unconditional input at that. Unless you have a way to reverse-engineer the dialog logic and/or insert navigation commands to ensure that the position is determined, you can't be sure. You may have to use some other technology to import the data.

Comment: Thanks, It seems that I have to upload all the fields at once.